# Does Clang have something like #pragma GCC target?

Tags: clang, intrinsics, avx, pragma

I have some code written that uses AVX intrinsics when they are available on the current CPU.  In GCC and Clang, unlike Visual C++, in order to use intrinsics, you must enable them on the command line.

The problem with GCC and Clang is that when you enable these options, you're giving the compiler free reign to use those instructions everywhere in your source file.  This is very bad when you have header files containing inline functions or template functions, because the compiler will generate these functions with AVX instructions.

When linking, duplicate functions will be discarded.  However, because some source files were compiled with `-mavx` and some were not, the various compilations of the inline/template functions will be different.  If you're unlucky, the linker will randomly choose the version that has AVX instructions, causing the program to crash when run on a system without AVX.

GCC solves this with `#pragma GCC target`.  You can turn off the special instructions for the header files, and the code generated will not use AVX:

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC target("no-avx")

#include "MyHeader.h"

#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Does Clang have anything like this?  It seems to ignore these options and generates AVX code anyway.

Comment: You note, "If you're unlucky, the linker will randomly choose the version that has AVX instructions, causing the program to crash when run on a system without AVX." But in your scenario, a header was compiled with AVX on because it was included in a translation unit that was compiled with AVX on. Any use of that translation unit can cause the same crash, yes?

Comment: @jbapple Yes, but the program would not call into functions in the AVX-enabled translation unit unless `cpuid` and `IsProcessorFeaturePresent` say that AVX is available.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are interested in FMV https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning. Clang as far as I know does not have it.

Comment: https://schd.ws/hosted_files/ossna2017/6b/Boosting_GLIBC_GCC.pdf

Comment: If you want a multi compiler solution then make your own cpu dispatcher.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Clang equivalent to `GCC push_options / GCC target / GCC pop_options` are the [`clang attribute push / clang attribute pop` pragmas](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#specifying-an-attribute-for-multiple-declarations-pragma-clang-attribute) along with the [`target` attribute](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#target):

```
#pragma clang attribute push (__attribute__((target("pclmul,sse4.1,ssse3"))), apply_to=function)
// ...
#pragma clang attribute pop
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC target("pclmul", "sse4.1", "ssse3")
// ...
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

Note that where the GCC `target` pragma takes a comma-delimited list of target options, the clang `target` attribute takes a single string, comma-delimited internally.

Clang supports negative target options (such as `"no-avx"`), but I prefer to use positive options to add to the feature set selected by command line options.

Comment: If I recall correctly, GCC supports `arch=haswell` (or whatever target) inside `target()` attributes.  On the command line that has the major advantage of also setting `tune=`; presumably that also works inside the attribute.  Maybe not so important with clang; it has less "weird" stuff that hurts new CPUs for the benefit of older CPUs (like gcc's default of ` -mavx256-split-unaligned-load` and store.)

Answer (score 7):

You should probably be using `static inline` instead of `inline`, so a version of a function compiled with `-mavx` will only be used by callers from that translation unit.

The linker will still merge actual duplicates, instead of just picking one non-inline definition by name.

This also has the advantage that the compiler doesn't waste time emitting a stand-alone definition for functions that it decides to inline into every caller in that translation unit.

---

The gcc/clang way makes sense if you're used to it and design your code for it.  And note that MSVC need AVX enabled if you're compiling functions that use AVX.  Otherwise it will mix VEX and non-VEX encodings, leading to big penalties, instead of using the VEX encoding for something like a 128-bit `_mm_add_ps` in a horizontal add at the end of a `_mm256_add_ps` loop.

So you basically have the same problem with MSVC, that compiling `_mm_whatever` will make AVX-only machine code.

Comment: Yeah.  I filed feedback with Microsoft about this problem on the Visual C++ end.  There just needs to be something similar to #pragma GCC target in all these compilers.

Comment: @Myria: `static inline` avoid the need for `#pragma` for non-template functions, though, right?  I guess there is a real problem for templated classes, though, because you can't make their methods `static inline`.  Is it really random, or does link order matter?  If you always have the AVX `.o` files last on the linker command line, maybe you're ok?

Comment: @PeterCordes, why not just `static` instead of `static inline`? What's the difference?

Comment: @Zboson: I don't think there is a real difference.  With `static`, the compiler is free to inline or not, but `inline` might be treated as a hint.  Unlike with non-`static`, where `inline` specifies different linkage behaviour.

Comment: I think the hint to the compiler to inline with static is about as useful nowadays as the register keyword.

Comment: @Zboson: yeah, I'd guess so.  But it has useful semantic meaning for humans, and is not out of place for something you're putting in header files.  If you really want to force inlining, you have to use `__attribute__((always_inline))`.  (Linux does that for some functions.  Maybe that's so you can build a debug / un-optimized kernel and have it be less terrible?  Or maybe it actually helps for some cases where the compiler wouldn't realize it was a really good idea.)

Comment: As to the OP's question does Clang have something equivalent to FMV in GCC https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FunctionMultiVersioning? FMV is what makes Clear Linux so great https://clearlinux.org/features/function-multiversioning-fmv